# Device does not debugging on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I start the Debugger and on External Device don´t make nothing, example:
-Open the app on Run
-Open the app on Debugger
-Result on Watches while Debugging

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this,

[You need verify before, your module apps configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5ekf.png)

[The Launch Option is disabled, that significcate when you compile the source code, don't make nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy8qT.png)

[You need click on Options, and select "Default Activity", after click "OK" or "Finish"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LwSM.png)

This worked to me,